# Is POST and URL automatically populated for HttpParameters?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

DO I need to specify POST and the URL as a parameter. I've tried multiple methods and I am getting an incorrect signature.

e.g

```
 parameters.put("HTTP Method", "POST").
 parameters.put("URL", "Example.com").
```

or it is automatically populated with :

```
HttpRequestAdapter _request_ = new HttpRequestAdapter(new HttpPost("Example.com"));
            HttpParameters _requestparameters = new HttpParameters();
            OAuthMessageSigner _signer = new HmacSha1MessageSigner();
```

Comment: I have and I am not getting the correct signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is automatically populate by :

```
 HttpRequestAdapter _request_ = new HttpRequestAdapter(new HttpPost("Example.com")
```

My signature was incorrect because I did not set consumer secret and token secret correctly.